# Hive - Drop table from another user

Tags: permissions, hive, hdfs, cloudera

I have a hive problem. I am working on a cloudera test cluster and disabled the permission management, so there is no ACL handling in Hive. 
Now I am able to drop a table of another user. Afterwards the table does not exist in the Hive metastore. The problem is, that the files in hdfs further exists.
So, if I create the same table again, it is filled with the old data, because the same hdfs parquet files.

All users are in the group hive.
All db files are granted with the following permissions: rwxrwxrwt

What do I have to change for dropping the table completely including the hdfs data ?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards
Jörn

Comment: can u post table generation script?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to Hue, File Browser and put the path where the data is present and you can delete it or move it to trash.

Answer (score 0):

The tables looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `schema.mytable`(
  `sysdate` string, 
  `sai` double, 
  `art_nr` double,  
  `fakturierf_kz` double, 
  `vek` double, 
  `bek` double)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `p_import_date` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://servername:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/mytable'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'parquet.compress'='SNAPPY', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1480519730');
```

Sure I can delete the files from shell with

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r myfolder
```

But this isn't really helpful. I would like to drop a table from another user like the user would do it.

Thank you